# How to link program to a controller class

Tags: java, javafx

I've been messing around with a little program I am making but I just cant seem to accomplish the connection of a program into my controller class.
This is a [java program that transforms images to ascii](https://gist.github.com/AnimeshShaw/8e6ba43f2cfb75331f40). My goal is to have an application similar to the one in the link activate upon the selection of an image through a file chooser. I am confident I am able to change its structure to accept images from a file chooser but I am not sure how to connect the two. Would it be best to re code everything within the actionEvent or is there some way that I am able to implement the finished program to the controller class. Thanks you!

```
@FXML
private void img(ActionEvent event3) throws IOException {

    FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();

    //Set extension filter
    FileChooser.ExtensionFilter extFilterJPG = new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("JPG files (*.jpg)", "*.JPG");
    FileChooser.ExtensionFilter extFilterPNG = new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("PNG files (*.png)", "*.PNG");
    fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().addAll(extFilterJPG, extFilterPNG);

    //Show open file dialog
    File file = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null) 
   }//img
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out! For anyone thats curious you can export it as a jar file and then import it into your project jar files and execute it!